# Render parent view from child view backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I have a main view and a modal window which is a child view from the parent view.

The modal consist of a form which is submitted via ajax.

How do I render the parent view from the child view after submitting the form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parent view can bind to notifications on the child view to know when the form was submitted. Then it can render itself:

On the parent view:

```
// Parent initialize
this.childView.on('formSubmitted', this.render, this);

// Parent removal
this.childView.off('formSubmitted', this.render, this);
```

On the child view:

```
// After form is submitted
this.trigger('formSubmitted');
```

The child will trigger a "formSubmitted" event and the parent's render function will be called.

Comment: Thanks works really good. Except that the child view somehow changes the model collection of the parent when saving. Can that be? When I do a page refresh the collection renders fine again

Comment: If the parent-view and child-view share the same model collection then any change to the model will be reflected in both views.

Comment: what if they are not using the same model?